# Generating SQL Server DB from Swagger WebAPI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-codegen

Having found Swagger and generated a WebAPI project for the 'pets' example, I figured the next logical step would be to generate the backend DB.  However none of the tutes I've come across recommend an approach for this.

I see there are notimplementedexceptions in the method stubs so it is agnostic to DB I suppose.  My questions:

a) Is there a 'recommended' way to generate the SQL tables as you would when you use the scaffolding to generate the API from a model class?

b) What is the accepted workflow when details of the API change?  Do a full regen of the server project from the Swagger editor then manually copy the calls to your repository into each stubbed method?  Then use migrations after changing the model?  Manual copies would be time consuming.

I'm not fussed between .net core core or aspnet WebAPI, whatever works I'm happy to go with.

Thanks

Comment: You find an easy way to do this? I was thinking of using the .cs model files generated from the swagger codegen and putting them into a edmx, then syncing that up to a database. Not sure if there's an easier way though - this way would still have a lot of manual stuff to it

Answer (score 2):

There's a decent OSS tool called [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) that works pretty well with swagger (even though based on [OAS](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification)). It will generate MySQL DDL from your model definitions.
P.S. I'm hacking on it to be able to generate Redshift DDL, would be great if folks contributed other DBs capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

> ##### Is there a 'recommended' way to generate the SQL tables [from Swagger / OpenAPI specs]?

As already suggested, I would go with the [MySQL schema generator of the OpenAPI Generator project](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/mysql-schema). I am not aware of an alternative tool so far.

> ##### What is the accepted workflow when details of the API change?

Not sure if an accepted workflow exists yet, but here's what I would do. The process is limited to using the PostgreSQL database, and does not use .NET Core or ASP.net WebAPI on the server side – only SQL.

1. **Obtain the OpenAPI spec file for your current API.** If you have Swagger UI installed, a simple option is this:

   1. Modify your Swagger UI URL by appending "`-json`". This will provide you with an OpenAPI spec document in JSON format. For example, if your Swagger UI HTML version of your API docs is at `http:/localhost:3000/docs/`, then this command will download the OpenAPI spec document in JSON format:

      ```
      wget http:/localhost:3000/docs-json -O myname.OpenAPISpec.json
      ```
   2. Convert the OpenAPI spec from JSON to YAML by using the [Swagger Online Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).
2. **Generate your SQL schema** from the OpenAPI spec document, using [OpenAPI Generator for MySQL](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/mysql-schema) as mentioned above. This step will be needed *only once*. Assuming you installed their CLI tool as `openapi-generator-cli`, you would use a command as follows (with more options as needed, there are a lot to choose from):

   ```
   mkdir schema &&
   openapi-generator-cli generate -g mysql-schema --skip-validate-spec \
     -i myname.OpenAPISpec.yaml -o schema
   ```
3. **Adapt your SQL schema manually** to clean it up and be compatible with PostgreSQL, and then create a PostgreSQL database from it. The manual adaptations needed can be quite extensive; for example, you do not want to create a separate table for each DTO definition of the API, but that is what the generator by default proposes. Don't expect this to be a fully automatic step – you rather just get a starting point.
4. **Install [PostgREST](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest)** and make it use your database. This is an open source tool that works in the opposite way as the OpenAPI schema generator for MySQL: it takes a database schema as the spec of a REST API, and generates both that API and a Swagger / OpenAPI spec as documentation for it.

   (If you also need file storage, a database admin backend or other additions, consider using [Supabase](https://github.com/sponsors/supabase), an open source Firebase alternative that is based on PostgREST. But note that their self-hostable version only allows one database per instance, in contrast to their commercial offerings – [see](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/4907).)
5. **When details of your API change**, you just change the PostgreSQL database schema. The API and Swagger / OpenAPI spec document will change automatically via PostgREST now. No manual intervention is needed, except for data migration / restructuring in the database – but this is now the one and only activity of changing the API.
6. **Generate an updated API client (optional)** from the updated OpenAPI spec document, now provided by PostgREST. For the generation, you can use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) or the [client generators of OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators#client-generators).

Note how this process also provides a way to transition from any API implementation with Swagger / OpenAPI specs to PostgREST. But don't expect the process to be painless … it's a novel way to use these tools together, so there will be friction …